# If I Ask a Question On Superuser and Decide its Better Suited for U&L can I Repost it Here?

Tags: discussion, support

I [asked a question on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1546095/altshift-not-working-getting-altiso-next-group-instead) about a keyboard issue with linux. I didn't get any helpful replies. It occured to me that people on U&L might be better equiped to help me with this problem. Is it okay if I repost it there?

Comment: If you delete the other one, sure.

Comment: It's now at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/583060/5132 .

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's fine. Just make sure you don't ask on both sites at once. If you want to move a question here, delete the one on Super User and then come and repost it here.